# How do I force PHP to load without waiting for ssh2

Tags: php, multithreading, ssh, stream

Currently I have a script that uses SSH2 to execute a c program on a server, however the webpage takes the x seconds to load that the script waits. Is there a way to make php send the command through ssh and not wait for the response? Thanks
My current code:

```
<?php
$ssh = ssh2_connect('********', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($ssh, 'root', '**********');
$stream = ssh2_exec($ssh, './sr1 80 4 400 400 20');
fclose($stream);
?>
```

(Censored server IP and Password for obvious reasons)

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to make an *asynchronous* request.

Comment: You could put that bit in its own file, and then just call that file from the main script with `exe()` it would then run synchronously

Comment: ssh2_exec is nonblocking by default. Perhaps your problem is the fclose. Do you have to call it right away?

Answer (score 1):

Using http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ ...

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('********', 22);
$ssh->login('root', '**********');
$ssh->enablePTY();
$ssh->exec('nohup ./sr1 80 4 400 400 20 &');
```

You can try it with and without the nohup and & but my guess is that they're necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your code in a [Thread](http://docs.php.net/Thread) in order to run it asynchronously:

```
<?php
class MySsh extends Thread {
    public function run() {
        $ssh = ssh2_connect('********', 22);
        ssh2_auth_password($ssh, 'root', '**********');
        $stream = ssh2_exec($ssh, './sr1 80 4 400 400 20');
        fclose($stream);
    }
}
$mySsh = new MySsh();
var_dump($mySsh->start());
?>
```

Note that to use `Thread`s in php, you need to have the [pthreads](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php) library installed.

Comment: With this I get this error displayed: "Fatal error: Class 'Thread' not found in " and the command is not sent.

Comment: @GeorgeWBush It's no more difficult than installing any other library to php. See [pthreads installation instructions](http://php.net/manual/en/pthreads.installation.php).

Comment: It appears to require you to uninstall php and reinstall php and edit the php source code which is not somthing i am comfortable doing. Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: @GeorgeWBush No problem. If you do decide that your application could benefit from multithreading in more places, then you might consider trying pthreads later on. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

ssh2_connect, ssh2_auth_password is required for ssh login.

ssh2_exec execute the command given second argument './sr1'. Can you please provide what exactly it does with snippets ?

Secondly, ssh2_exec : Execute a command on a remote server. and I think it will wait for your command to complete the execution and then return.

Can you try using ssh2_shell : Request an interactive shell

You can probably, open shell and invoke your command to run background or in different process and exit from shell. I think it can be more faster then ssh2_exec.

Answer (score 0):

it works for me:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('host', 22);
ssh2_exec($connection, "screen -dmS 'sr-script' ./sr1 80 4 400 400 20 2>&1");
```